# Can I use GET and POST with the same asp mvc .net Controller?

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, forms, controller, http-post

Using asp .net mvc, I submit a form using post and also using get. In my controller I can only access the post argument, but not the GET ones.

Here is my HTML form:

```
<form name="input" action="/account/Login/?test=123" method="post">
   Username: <input type="text" name="username">
   Lastname: <input type="text" name="lastname">
   Password: <input type="text" name="password">
<input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

My controller:

```
[AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Get | HttpVerbs.Post)]
public ActionResult Login(User model)
{
   string test = Request.QueryString["test"]; // this is null
}
```

I also tried this for my controller, but to no avail...

```
[AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Get | HttpVerbs.Post)]
    public ActionResult Login(User model, string test)
    {
        // but "test" is also  null
    }
```

Comment: Are fields for User model binded normally after post?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your example works perfectly for me. In both variats of actions I get test=123

Alternatively you can try to use `Html.BeginForm()` helper:

```
@using(Html.BeginForm("Account", "Login", new { test = "123" }, FormMethod.Post))
{
   @:Username: <input type="text" name="username"/>
   @:Lastname: <input type="text" name="lastname"/>
   @:Password: <input type="text" name="password"/>
   <input type="submit" value="Submit"/>
}
```

Comment: and how do you get test ? like this string test = Request.QueryString["test"]; ? Can you show me your controller please ?

Comment: Yes, and the second way (with string test as second parameter) work for me. So I asked you if you get User model binded with data from form?

Comment: what do you mean by "User model binded ith data from form" ? Sorry I'm still a beginner. Thanks for your help btw

Comment: Can you set breakpoint on string test = Request.QueryString["test"]; and lunch it with debug. Then fill inputs inside your form and submit it. Do you see the data from the form inside User model when you get breakpoint?

Answer (score 0):

That's not how HTTP verbs work.

GET and POST aren't two ways to pass data; they're two different types of HTTP requests.  (only POST has a payload)

---

You're asking for a *query string parameter*.

However, the browser strips query string parameters from form action URLs.
The HTTP request doesn't include that at all.

Instead, you should put it in an `<input type="hidden">`.

Comment: thans you for your answer, then how can I have access to the username, lastname, password and also test ? I can't pass it with hidden I really need to have access to test using get method

Comment: @user2037696: What do you mean?